# Change background color of xib file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, xib

I know this is a basic question but I'm blanking out when it comes to this... I was able to change the background color via the xib UI, but when I run the program it doesn't change the color and reverts back to the default color. Do I need to do something else besides change the color in the right hand side column?
[image]

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you create the APP from the Utility Application template ok?

if so, take a look in the FlipsideViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];  
}
```

delete the second line !

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I found the answer. There is some default code in the `viewDidLoad` method that I needed to delete. Can someone confirm this?

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];`